# Using Room instead singleton

Tags: android, android-room

I noticed that Room lib has a Builder called `inMemoryDatabaseBuilder`, in Android Room documentation says:

> Creates a RoomDatabase.Builder for an in memory database. Information
>   stored in an in memory database disappears when the process is killed.
>   Once a database is built, you should keep a reference to it and re-use
>   it.

I ever used singleton to keep session object in memory and never used Room for inMemory database, my question is:
It's a good pratic to use Room instead Singleton for storing session data in memory?
Singleton is a bad pratic at all?
I need in memory, because this session data are only used when the user are using the app, if the app is killed, this session data cannot persist...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is structured and you need to retrieve it in different ways (order or filtering), it's a good idea to use an SQLite in-memory database.

Keep in mind that Room database is built as a singleton too because database access has to be "managed" in multithread situations.

Remember to create it in the `onCreate` method of your `Application` class.